# Add sort to Angular factory

Tags: json, angularjs

I want to add a sort function to my factory controller in Angular JS.
I have got as far as what I have below:

```
var albumsApp = angular.module ('albumsApp',[])


        albumsApp.factory('albumFactory',function($http) {
        return {
            getAlbumsAsync: function(callback,$scope){

                $http.get('albums.json').success(callback);
                },

            };


        });
        albumsApp.controller ('albumController', function ($scope,albumFactory) {
            albumFactory.getAlbumsAsync(function(results){
            console.log('albumController async returned value');
            $scope.albums = results.albums;
                });
            albumFactory.changeSorting(function(results){
            console.log('changeSorting called');

                });

        });
```

I get an error **"TypeError: albumFactory.changeSorting is not a function"** (this refers to the **albumFactory.changeSorting**) as I have not added it to the factory. I don't know how to do this.
The html code I am using is below: I want to call the function to sort what is in the JSON file alphabetically

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="modules/app.js" ></script>

</script>
<title>
</title>

</head>
<body ng-app="albumsApp">
<div data-ng-controller="albumController">
    <!-- <ul data-ng-repeat="album in albums| orderBy:'title'"> -->
    <ul data-ng-repeat="album in albums">
    <li>
      Artist is "{{album.artist}}" and title is "{{album.title}}"

    </li>
  </ul>  
<button data-ng-click="changeSorting()">Description</button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The JSON list is below:

```
{
    "albums":[    
      {
      "artist": "Arctic Monkeys",
      "title": "AM"
       },
       {
      "artist": "Nirvana",
      "title": "Nevermind"
       },
       {
      "artist": "Buck 65",
      "title": "Man Overboard"    
      }
      ]

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `orderBy` in your `ng-repeat` ? ex: `ng-repeat="album in albums | orderBy:'album.artist'"`

Comment: Because it has to be done by a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is not directly connected to the Angular service—all methods called from the view should be in your controller. You should have a method on your controller  and not in your factory. Try moving that function to your controller:

```
albumsApp.controller ('albumController', function ($scope,albumFactory) {
    albumFactory.getAlbumsAsync(function(results){
        console.log('albumController async returned value');
        $scope.albums = results.albums;
    });

    $scope.changeSorting = function (){
        // your logic goes here
        console.log('changeSorting called');
    });
});
```

You can keep your logic in your controller. You can use `orderBy` in Angular's [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) module to help you sort:

```
$filter('orderBy')(array, expression, reverse)
```

Comment: Tina answered it correctly, my answer appeared above her post, I don't know why, I must have made a mistake while posting it.

Comment: You should post a comment to an answer instead of a new answer, that is why your answer is showing up. You can delete your answer and post it as a comment and up-vote my answer and mark as best answer :)

Comment: I haven't got sufficient reps to up-vote yet. There are too many characters in the entire code to post it as a comment but if anybody wants the code they can message me. I have marked Tina's answer as the best.